# Regex for searching Database-Statements in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, regex, visual-studio-2008

I am currently working on a rather large project in Visual Studio 2008 with a lot of Database-Statements. The Statements are held in strings like this:

```
string stmt = "SELECT ID, OTHER " +
         "FROM TABLE " +
         "WHERE CONDITION";
```

I was wondering how to find all Statements via regex. So I am not so good at regex, but maybe someone got any idea? I don't know if it's impossible because of the multilining? Does it work with the search inside Visual Studio?

EDIT to answer of Clement: Well SQL-Statements are not only SELECT-Statements, in my case there are also a lot of UPDATE- and INSERT-Statements. But what if there other eg. CREATE-Statements?

Answer (score 1):

CTRL + F, Choose "Active Project", and specify "SELECT" as token, no ?

Answer (score 1):

Run a regular expression that uses the '|' operator which acts as an or.  An example would be this:

Text To Search
"INSERT INTO table;  SELECT * FROM table; UPDATE table; DELETE FROM table"

RegEx expression
INSERT|SELECT|UPDATE|DELETE

This returns these values along with their index
INSERT
SELECT
UPDATE
DELETE